# Space Tree with Manhattan Edges

Tags: infovis

Is it possible to create Manhattan Style edges in a space tree using inforVis/jit.

It is not an option on: http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Options/Options-Edge-js.html. But i see that custom edges are possible.

Has anyone already done this?

Comment: By Manhattan Edges you mean squared edges?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured this out already (and for other readers)...

While passing constructor options, try specifying edge `type` as `bent:line`, somewhat like the following.

```
Edge: {
    type: 'bent:line',
    overridable: true,
    color: "#000000",
    lineWidth: 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Spacetree-js.html#ST.Plot.EdgeTypes

ST.Plot.EdgeTypes

This class contains a list of Graph.Adjacence built-in types.  Edge types implemented are ‘none’, ‘line’, ‘arrow’, ‘quadratic:begin’, ‘quadratic:end’, ‘bezier’.
You can add your custom edge types, customizing your visualization to the extreme.